# Sharing with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Ok really easy one.I just want to click a button and share something from my WP8.1 application.

In WP8 is was dead easy but I understand from reading articles this has changed which makes sense. The only problem is it doesn't work, well at least not for me. So I'm asking for a little help and before you post the same article that I have already read a dozen times please don't. I have included links to several articles of that I have read and probably read around 50 more with the same or similar examples that just don't do anything.

Please only suggest or post code that you know works (i.e. you have used it in your own application and know it to be working)

I have honestly reviewed about 50 odd articles (samples below) that just don't work. I'll continue to research and if I find something I'll post it up.

[Share text to facebook from Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141730/share-text-to-facebook-from-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1)

And numerous versions of this

[How to use ShareLinkTask namespace in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924949/how-to-use-sharelinktask-namespace-in-windows-phone-8-1/24926234#24926234)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishasingh/archive/2013/01/16/sharing-data-from-a-windows-store-app-using-winrt-api.aspx

[How to use ShareLinkTask namespace in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924949/how-to-use-sharelinktask-namespace-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: What does "The only problem is it doesn't work, well at least not for me" mean.  What code have you tried already, and what happens when it runs

Comment: I have tried all of the examples in the links added to my post plus around 50 more (no seriously) what happens, absolutely nothing. No error, nothing

Comment: Do you want to share with windows 8 and windows phone 8 ? with external devices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll make a small edit to one of the posts you already mentioned.

This is the way it is working for me:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += ShareData;
}

private async void ShareData(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataRequest request = args.Request;
        var deferral = request.GetDeferral();
        request.Data.Properties.Title = "Title";
        request.Data.Properties.Description = "Description";
        request.Data.SetText("The text to share");
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

private void btnShareLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

Comment: Can we keep title empty, if anyone wants to share only Text.